# glCopyBufferSubData Segmentation Fault SIGSEGV

Tags: java, opengl-es

I've recently stumbled on a problem that took a few hours to pin down. On a desctop PC my code worked fine, but on a Vivante embedded device it crashed with segmentation fault on a seemingly good code.

Here's the code:

```
// get our VBO
            vboID = vboIDList.get(1);
            glBindBuffer(GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER, vboID);

            // create new buffer and copy data
            int newVboID = glGenBuffers();
            glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, newVboID);
            indexBuffer = MemoryUtil.memAllocInt(indexBufferLength);
            indexBuffer.put(new int[indexBufferLength]).flip();
            glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

            glCopyBufferSubData(GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER, GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, 0, indexCount * INT_SIZE);      
            //INT_SIZE is a static final = 4

            //replace VBO
            vboIDList.set(1, newVboID);
            glDeleteBuffers(vboID);

            // unbind buffers
            glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
            glBindBuffer(GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER, 0);
```

it crashed on glBufferSubData with no clear reason.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out that in a rare case indexCount was equal 0, so I was trying to copy 0 bytes. Some drivers handle this well, but others do not.
Just in case someone stumbles on this too, that's my answer. Check for a positive copy length before calling glCopyBufferSubData().